# Use S3 target in cloudformation for a codepipeline deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CodePipeline in the AWS console its possible to specify a S3 deploy step https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html I'd like to be able to do this exactly, but in cloudformation. I'm missing something obvious here. Any help appreciated.

I was able to get a source and build step in cloudformation for the pipeline, but not the deploy step. The provider for that step I would think would be s3, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample deploy step for S3

```
{
    "Name": "Deploy",
    "Actions": [
        {
            "Name":"Push-Lambda-Artifacts",
            "ActionTypeId": {
                "Category": "Deploy",
                "Owner": "AWS",
                "Provider": "S3",
                "Version": "1"
            },
            "InputArtifacts": [
                {
                    "Name": "lambda"
                }
            ],
            "Configuration":{
                "BucketName": {
                    "Ref": "BucketName"
                },
                "Extract": true
            },
            "RunOrder": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I think that will get you most of the way there. InputArtifacts is from an output from my codebuild step.